# I want to print the first character of the first string from an array of Strings and the last character from the last string from that Array

Tags: java

I don't know what is the issue, I tried debugging but I couldn't understand why it's not working

```
class Solution {
    public void sol(String s) {
        String [] parts = s.split(" ");

        int left = 0;
        int right = parts.length - 1;

        System.out.println(parts[left].charAt(left)); // ->this is correct
        System.out.println("_____________");
        System.out.println(parts[right].charAt(right));// wrong output
    }
 }
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        s.sol("Don't read this");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the last character of the last string. So first find the length of the last string `parts[right].length()` then get the index of the last character by reducing one from it.

```
System.out.println(parts[right].charAt(parts[right].length()-1));
```

Comment: but, for the first string I am doing it right? to find the first letter of the first string in the string array

Comment: Yes, because the first string and first character both have zero index.

Comment: I think the question title is just kind of badly worded. I think the array of strings he's referring to is the result of him splitting the original string. So I think `parts[right]` is all you actually need

Comment: @SamSpade yes the array of strings is what you have described. But he wants the last character of the last string in the array.

Comment: @MiladQasemi I see what you're saying. I read it as `.split("")` instead of `.split(" ")` I thought the purpose of splitting the string was just to get an array of single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
        System.out.println(parts[left].charAt(0));
        System.out.println("_____________");
        System.out.println(parts[right].charAt(parts[right].length()-1));
```

Okay, so for `System.out.println(parts[left].charAt(0))` lets break it down. Let's say the string is "sample string". That means:

parts = ["sample", "string"]

So we want to get the letter "s" from "sample". So we need to get `parts[0]` first, that gets us "sample." Then we want to get the first letter (or rather zeroth letter). So that's `parts[0].charAt(0)`. That should be the letter "s"

Next we want the last letter of the last word. That means we want the "g" from "string". So first we need to get the last word. There are 2 items in the list, so the index of the last word will be `2 - 1 = 1` Where 2 is the length of the list. Thus:

`int right = parts.length - 1;`

So now we can access the word string (or whatever the last word may happen to be) like this:

```
string lastWord = parts[right]
```

To get the last character, we do almost the same thing. We need to know first how long the string is, then we need to subtract one and get the character at that index. Thus:

```
int rightIndexOfRightWord = lastWord.length() - 1;
string lastChar = lastWord.charAt(rightIndexOfRightWord);
```

Put it all together and we get this little block of code:

```
int right = parts.length - 1;
string lastWord = parts[right]
int rightIndexOfRightWord = lastWord.length() - 1;
string lastChar = lastWord.charAt(rightIndexOfRightWord);
```

We can then combine all of that into one line:

```
int right = parts.length - 1;

string lastWord = parts[parts.length - 1]
string lastChar = lastWord.charAt(lastWord.length() - 1);
```

```
int right = parts.length - 1;
string lastChar = parts[parts.length - 1].charAt(parts[parts.length - 1].length() - 1);
```

done!

Comment: oh, so basically I'm checking twice, and I'm making a confusion?

Comment: @JAVA sort of? So imagine you have numbered rocks. parts[left] is saying "take the 10th rock". `s.charAt(left)` is saying the same thing. By chaining them and writing `parts[left].charAt(left)` you're saying "take the 10th rock, then take the 10th piece of that rock." Which doesn't really make sense

Comment: @JAVA Milad Qasemi is right, my soloution is wrong because I misread the problem. I'll fix it momentarily, but credit to him.

Comment: ok, but please explain in details for both cases, for the first string and also for the last string, cause I'm confused

Comment: @JAVA edits made, let me know if that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(str.charAt(0));//to print first character of the first string
System.out.println(str.charAt(str.length()-1));// to print last character of the last string
```

Comment: Does not work as advertised. This just prints the first/last character of a string called `str`.

Comment: When posting an answer, please include any needed explanation, not just a line or two of code.